# Motherboard is not providing output or giving beeps

Tags: motherboard, bios, computer-building, desktop-computer, cmos

This is an email I sent to the ASRock motherboard company's support email address. My motherboard will power my heat sink fan, my LEDs, the powerbutton, and even my SSD. I am getting no output from the HDMI or VGA slots though, and if no memory is installed I get no error beeps from my motherboard. I have taken the battery out overnight, and shorted the CMOS. What am I missing?

"Motherboard: FM2+a88x- ITX+ 
APU: A10-7870k Quad-Core, integrated graphics CPU from AMD 
Memory: 12 GB (8 + 4) GSkill 1600 
Video Card: Integrated on CPU  
Operating System: none yet 
Hard Drive: Silicon Power 250 GB 
BIOS: 2.50

When I have every single cord plugged in and RAM modules in (I've tried just one module in each slot) the CPU heat sink fan will spin and the power supply fan will spin.

The motherboard gives no beeps when memory is not in, and I have the speaker plugged in. I've reseated everything three times, but I get no video output. I've used HDMI and VGA. Is it possible that I get no beep codes because the APU isn't directly supported until bios 3.0? If so can ASRock update my bios due to the fact that I can't boot to flash it? Any insight would be extremely helpful!"

Comment: Have you tried the monitor setup before (VGA connector and monitor).

Comment: @RACING121 No, but I don't even get a post error beep, so would it even be relevant?

Comment: If the motherboard isn't even attempting to POST I would RMA it immediately.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do! Awesome, thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure the speaker is functioning and attached to the motherboard properly, and you remove all the RAM and get no beeps, then your board is not performing its [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

The minimum components you need to POST (in most cases) is a PSU, a motherboard and a CPU.  If you remove everything except the PSU, motherboard and CPU and you still don't get any POST then I'd say either your motherboard (more likely) or CPU (much less likely) are faulty, and need to be replaced.

You may want to try a known-working PSU first, just because it'll be easiest to try, and will eliminate the PSU as a potential problem.

But everything you're describing sounds like a faulty motherboard to me.

Now, if this configuration *never* worked, and you suspect that it's because your current BIOS revision doesn't support a newer CPU, then that could very well cause it.  The usual way to fix that is to install a compatible CPU, update your BIOS, and then install the newer CPU.